# Does transpose commute through expectation?

Tags: matrix, covariance

Working with the generalized covariance formula for a vector $x$, I have the following:

$$E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T)] = E(xx^T) - \mu E(x^T)$$

But the term $E(x^T)$ doesn't make much sense to me.  Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting this term with my matrix algebra?

Answer (score 17):

The short answer is "yes",  $E(x^T) = E(x)^T=\mu^T$.  Your full expression will be:

$E[(x−μ)(x−μ)^T)]=E(xx^T)−μE(x^T)-E(x)\mu^T+\mu\mu^T = E(xx^T)-\mu\mu^T$

The expectation operator doesn't care about the shape of the vector or matrix it operates on.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a direction for the long answer or a reference?  I'm very curious about the fundamental reason.

Comment: Looking at the simplest non-trivial example can help.  For instance, when $\mathbf{x}$ is a row vector of length 2, say with components $x_1$ and $x_2$, then $\mathbf{x}^t$ is a column vector of length 2 with components $x_1$ and $x_2$.  The expectations are $E[x_1]$ and $E[x_2]$: these are the components of $E[\mathbf{x}]$ and $E[\mathbf{x}^t]$; the only difference is that in the first case they are arranged side-by-side in the row vector and in the second they are arranged top-to-bottom in the column vector.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer confirmed, the answer is yes. Actually, even complex transposing commutes through expectation, meaning:
$$\mathbb{E}[x^H] = \mathbb{E}[x]^H $$